# PHP including all variables with the same prefix

Tags: php

Hello I am looking for a way to include multiple php variables without using the exact name but a common variable (ie: $nav_***) does anyone know of a simple way of doing this?

My goal is to be able to include these variables into an array and use them in my webpage as a nav bar or something of that sort.

```
var.php
<?php
$nav_link1 = "link";
$nav_link2 = "link2";
$nav_home = "home";
$nav_search = "search";
?>
proccess.php
$nav = array($nav_***);
nav.php
// haven't created this one yet i'm taking it one step at a time


// new var.php
$nav['home'] = "home.php";
$nav['info'] = "info.php";
$nav['ect'] = "ect";
// would this work the same as an array?
```

Comment: Why don't you use an array in the first place? `$nav = array('link1' => ..., 'link2' => ...);`

Comment: If you really must, you can combine [`get_defined_vars()`](http://php.net/get_defined_vars), `array_keys`, `preg_grep`, and `array_intersect_key` or just list known ones with [`compact()`](http://php.net/compact).

Comment: mainly because the file is still being worked on and i would hate to have to go throught and add each variable to the array by hand each time i add a new one. (ie: the variables are in a file called var.php, var gets called by another file named proccess.php that takes the variables and makes them into an array, that array is then fed to a script called nav.php that then takes each variable and creates a link for it.) var.php => proccess.php => nav.php   also this is the simple explanation the links and what not go through other scripts indirectly as well

Comment: Again, the real answer is to use a sane data structure, like an array, to begin with. This is not a typical problem a typical programmer encounters, because this is not a very sane way to store your data.

Comment: think you could be a little clearer? i'm still a newbie at php so any help you can offer about syntax and better ways to code are very much appreciated

Comment: It's not that much work to add variables to an array. `$nav = array()` then you can set `$nav['whatever'] = 'a value';` as many times as you want with different keys and values throughout the script. Or you can do a multi-line `$nav = array( 'one' => 'value', 'two' => 'value', 'three' => 'value', )` - each `key => value` declaration is its own line and you're allowed to have a comma at the end of each line even if it's followed by a closing `)` bracket.

Comment: @mario in this case `$GLOBAL` works just as well actually.

Comment: Should wait more than 3 minutes.  You accepted so I'll not post an answer now.

Comment: @AbraCadaver that comment seemed a little mean... You'll with hold information from a newbie just because they found a useful answer that worked for his situation and accepted it as an answer? Asking questions is how people learn maybe if you had posted an answer that had been better than sjagr's answer i could have changed which post i accepted as an answer... his answer worked for the situation perhaps if yours had worked better i would have changed my vote..

Comment: this community doesn't seem very newbie friendly i received 3 down votes simply because i didn't understand something and asked others to help me out and teach me how to do somthing better... I hope the rest of the community isn't this bad about newbies...

Comment: Yes that was a little mean I'm in a foul mood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm making this an answer because I can't demonstrate the multi-line part in the comments. You can solve your problem much better by setting an empty array then adding elements to them after the fact:

```
$nav = array();
$nav['link1'] = "link";
$nav['link2'] = "link2";
$nav['home'] = "home";
$nav['search'] = "search";
```

It's also not that much work to create `$nav` in just one go in a multi-line format:

```
$nav = array(
    'link1' => 'link',
    'link2' => 'link2',
    'home' => 'home',
    'search' => 'search', // The comma is okay - PHP doesn't mind, try it!
    // Add new lines here
);
```

It's simple to add more lines to this array declaration:

```
$nav = array(
    'link1' => 'link',
    'link2' => 'link2',
    'home' => 'home',
    'search' => 'search',
    'newlink' => 'newlink',
);
```

and you can still declare more values after the fact with no problems. If you do it this way, `process.php` doesn't need to even exist.

Comment: Or if these variables are static like menu items and your `vars.php` is essentially functioning as a configruation file then you could use something like `ini`, `yaml`, `json`, etc. instead of a raw php array. Granted `json` isnt much easier to work with than php but yaml and ini are pretty human readable and more maintainable than just having an array included.

Comment: @prodigitalson I am a big fan of `yaml` - probably a good reason why most of my projects are Symfony-based. [Bonus library if OP is interested!](https://code.google.com/p/php-yaml/)

Comment: @sjagr thank you for the library i will diffidently check that out!